# Make a Form extend until it reaches a maximum Width and Height

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-code

It always goes too far the same with height and everything is off-center because the Form gets bigger than intended.

Code:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Width += 3;
    if (this.Width >= 800)
    {
        timer1.Stop();
        timer2.Start();
    }
} 

private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Height += 3;
    if (this.Height >= 500)
    {
        timer2.Stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: When you say "It always goes too far", do you mean the window grows to the size you want but it grows past the edge of your screen?

Comment: No, it grows over the size I want never over the screen.

Comment: Is the *size I want* a numeric value or a *visual appearance*? What is the value of Width and Height when the Timers stop? Is your app DpiAware?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're increasing the height and width by three pixels, meaning it's going to skip a lot of numbers and your If Statements are setup incorrectly for that.

Take your width **If Statement** for example, you're saying "Stop when the width is *Greater or Equal* to 800", by having **Greater or Equal** in your If Statement you're allowing your application to grow past your desired size and since the window is increasing by three it's easy for it to skip over 800.

You should change your code so you're incrementing on even numbers.

```
if(this.Width % 2 == 1)
    this.Width += 3;
else if(this.Width % 2 == 0)
    this.Width += 2;

        if (this.Width >= 800)
        {
            timer1.Stop();
            timer2.Start();
        }
```

The code above is very sloppy but it should work until you find a better solution or once it has passed your desired size change it back manually since it should only be off by a few numbers according to your posted code.

```
this.Width += 3;
        if (this.Width >= 800)
        {
            timer1.Stop();
            this.Width == 800;
            timer2.Start();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the form's MaximumSize property, either in the constructor or in the designer:

```
this.MaximumSize = new Size(800, 500);
```

Comment: I just tried that I had it set in the designer already this still did not work.

Comment: @Rj1234 Define did not work?  I used your code and it won't exceed those dimensions.

Comment: The same exact thing happened it got bigger than desired.

Comment: @Rj1234 Well, how big did it get?  Dimensions bigger than 800 x 500?

Comment: Yes, does it change the fact that the form border style is set to None?

Comment: @Rj1234 BorderStyle.None did not make it exceed the maximum size.  Try recreating this issue in a new project with minimal code.  You must have a setting somewhere that removes the MaximumSize or you are looking at the wrong form, etc.